# SQL - Updating one table with data from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situation here which I'm not sure of what to do. It's about updating a certain field of one table based on the data coming from a different table. I have done it already but there's one concern. It's hard to explain but let me just show you an example of the following tables:

```
tbl_attendance:

| Stud_ID | Stud_Name     |
| 0       | Doe John      |
| 0       | Marquiz, Jane |
| 0       | Mason, Sheena |


tbl_classlist

| Stud_ID | Stud_Name          |
| 0001    | Doe, John          |
| 0002    | Marquez, Jane      |
| 0003    | Mason, Sheyna Kaye |
```

The situation is that after fetching all the records previously recorded from a csv file, there have been so much clerical errors committed around 2000+.

How would I be able to update the tbl_attendance Stud_ID field with Stud_ID coming from the tbl_classlist?

So far my code is this:

```
 UPDATE tbl_attendance A 
 INNER JOIN tbl_classlist B on A.Stud_Name=B.Stud_Name
 SET A.Stud_ID = B.Stud_ID;
```

But surely this won't work.

Comment: 'won't work' means what?

Comment: @john Anthony create a foreign key relationship between those two  tables and set update rule as CASCADE. It will automatically update the child table values when the parent columns value changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tabl_attendence;
    # stud_id, stud_name
    '0', 'Doe John'
    '0', 'Marquiz, Jane'
    '0', 'Mason, Sheena'

SELECT * FROM tabl_classlist;
# stud_id, stud_name
'001', 'Doe, John'
'002', 'Marquiz, Jane'
'003', 'Mason, Sheena'

update tabl_attendence a set a.stud_id =
(select replace(c.stud_id, 0, '') from tabl_classlist c
where replace(c.stud_name, ',', '') = replace(a.stud_name, ',', ''))
where (select replace(c.stud_id, 0, '') from tabl_classlist c
where replace(c.stud_name, ',', '') = replace(a.stud_name, ',', ''));

commit;

SELECT * FROM tabl_attendence;
# stud_id, stud_name
'1', 'Doe John'
'2', 'Marquiz, Jane'
'3', 'Mason, Sheena'
```

Few assumptions:

1. I assume the stud_id is varchar2 in tabl_classlist and number in tabl_attendence. 2. I assume that the student name has missing commas as in Doe John.

Even this will work:

```
update tabl_attendence a set a.stud_id =
(select replace(c.stud_id, 0, '') from tabl_classlist c
where replace(c.stud_name, ',', '') = replace(a.stud_name, ',', ''))
where a.stud_id = 0;

commit;
```